# What does "one little pop" means here?

Tags: meaning

In British Movie "Pirate Radio", There is scene where *Elanore* broke with *Simon* because *Elanore* fallen love with *Gavin*  & *Simon* sit with crew members discuss his feelings with them.

> Simon: Can you tell me one thing? Before she left this morning, did
>   you. . . You didn't. . .You know?
>
> Gavin: **Just one little pop.**

What does "one little pop" means here?

Comment: Maybe Definition #7? http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pop

Comment: In the UK this film was released as " The Boat that Rocked"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably means a kiss.

It's been a while since I've seen that movie. But judging by the context you've given and my memory, I think Simon is asking Gavin if anything romantic (and probably physical) happened between him and Elenore that morning. But he's too embarrassed to ask directly, and then Gavin responds in slang. I think it means "just one little kiss".

It could mean more than that (more passionate, more physical, whatever), but it would depend on more of the context. Do we see the moment before Elenore leaves in the movie and know that she kissed Gavin? Or are we taking Gavin's word for it? He could be using slang to be vague or because he is lying, or to spare Simon's feelings. A lot of things are possible depending on how the moment works in the movie.

But I think it probably means a kiss.